# Drop down with automated email Macro

Tags: drop-down-menu, macros, email-validation

I am trying to create a project tracker and the stakeholder who the project belongs to will be in column H. In Sheet 2 I created the list validation under Column D with the stakeholders names and Column E has their email address. I want to automatically send an email when in Sheet 1, column H drop down selects whoever the stakeholder is.

In the email header, I want it to say " Project Update: " & " " & Range("$b 2").Value 
B2 on Sheet 1 is the project name. So for each row, when column H has the drop down selected for the stake holder, I want it to send them an email automatically with their project name in the subject line.

This is what I have so far, but it's not getting the job done. Please help MACRO Gods.

I have the following in Sheet 1 VBA

```
Option Explicit
Public MailADD As String
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:H")) Is Nothing Then
    SendMe
    End If
    End Sub
```

Then in Module 1, I have the following.

```
Sub SendMe()
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Title As String
  Dim OutlApp As Object
  Dim HyperlinkMe As String
  Dim fnd As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim MailADD As String

  With ActiveSheet
      fnd = Range("H1").Value
    If fnd <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=fnd, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                MailADD = Rng.Offset(, 1).Value
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If
    fnd = Range("b1").Value
    HyperlinkMe = Range("l1").Value

    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
    Title = "Project Update: " & " " & Range("$b2").Value

  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  OutlApp.Visible = True
  On Error GoTo 0

  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

    .Subject = Title
    .To = MailADD
    .CC = ""
    .Body = "Hello," & vbLf & "Please review the link below of the BA CCS Project tracker for an update on your project" & vbLf & vbLf & HyperlinkMe & vbLf & vbLf _
          & "Regards," & vbLf _
          & Application.UserName & vbLf & vbLf


    On Error Resume Next
    .Display
    '.Send
    'Application.Visible = True
    If Err Then
      MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
    Else
      MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

 If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit

End With
  Set OutlApp = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Anyone? Any help would be appreciated.